# Can't drive any matched public keys in "mbedtls_ecdh_context" from certificate and private key file using mbedtls

Tags: c, x509certificate, public-key, mbedtls

The following is the code to drive public keys from certificates and private key files, which are generated based on ECC curve MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP521R1.
I like to put the correct public key into mbedtls_ecdh_context structures using mbedtls api functions. It is implemented with mbedtls v.3.3.0.
Where are mistakes in the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "mbedtls/platform.h"
#include "mbedtls/error.h"
#include "mbedtls/ecdh.h"
#include "mbedtls/entropy.h"
#include "mbedtls/ctr_drbg.h"
#include "mbedtls/pk.h"
#include "mbedtls/x509_crt.h"

static void hexdump(void const *bptr, size_t bytes)
{
    unsigned char *origin = (unsigned char *)(bptr);
    unsigned block = 0x10;
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t lower = block * (offset / block);
    size_t upper = block + lower;
    size_t index = 0;
    char buffer[ADDRSIZE + 72];
    char *output;

    while (lower < bytes)
    {
        output = buffer + ADDRSIZE;
        for (index = lower; output-- > buffer; index >>= 4)
        {
            *output = DIGITS_HEX[index & 0x0F];
        }
        output = buffer + ADDRSIZE;
        for (index = lower; index < upper; index++)
        {
            *output++ = ' ';
            if (index < offset)
            {
                *output++ = ' ';
                *output++ = ' ';
            }
            else if (index < bytes)
            {
                *output++ = DIGITS_HEX[(origin[index] >> 4) & 0x0F];
                *output++ = DIGITS_HEX[(origin[index] >> 0) & 0x0F];
            }
            else
            {
                *output++ = ' ';
                *output++ = ' ';
            }
        }
        *output++ = ' ';
        for (index = lower; index < upper; index++)
        {
            if (index < offset)
            {
                *output++ = ' ';
            }
            else if (index < bytes)
            {
                unsigned c = origin[index];
                *output++ = isprint(c) ? c : '.';
            }
            else
            {
                *output++ = ' ';
            }
        }
        *output++ = '\n';
        *output++ = '\0';
        printf("%s", buffer);
        // fputs (buffer, stdout);
        lower += block;
        upper += block;
    }
    if (bytes)
    {
        output = buffer;
        *output++ = '\n';
        *output++ = '\0';
        printf("%s", buffer);
        // fputs (buffer, stdout);
    }
    // fflush (stdout);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mbedtls_ecdh_context ctx_bob, ctx_pub_bob;
    mbedtls_entropy_context entropy;
    mbedtls_ctr_drbg_context ctr_drbg;
    mbedtls_pk_context pk_bob;
    mbedtls_x509_crt crt_bob;

    int ret;

    mbedtls_ecdh_init(&ctx_bob);
    mbedtls_ecdh_init(&ctx_pub_bob);
    mbedtls_entropy_init(&entropy);
    mbedtls_ctr_drbg_init(&ctr_drbg);
    mbedtls_pk_init(&pk_bob);
    mbedtls_x509_crt_init(&crt_bob);

    // Initialize RNG and entropy source
    if ((ret = mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed(&ctr_drbg, mbedtls_entropy_func, &entropy, NULL, 0)) != 0)
    {
        mbedtls_printf(" failed\n  ! mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed returned -0x%04X\n", -ret);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if ((ret = mbedtls_pk_parse_keyfile(&pk_bob, KEY_FILE, NULL, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &ctr_drbg)) != 0)
    {
        mbedtls_printf(" failed\n  ! mbedtls_pk_parse_keyfile returned -0x%04X\n", -ret);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    mbedtls_ecp_keypair *bob_keypair = mbedtls_pk_ec(pk_bob);

    if ((ret = mbedtls_ecdh_get_params(&ctx_bob, bob_keypair, MBEDTLS_ECDH_OURS)) != 0)
    {
        mbedtls_printf(" failed\n  ! mbedtls_ecdh_get_params returned -0x%04X\n", -ret);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if ((ret = mbedtls_ecdh_gen_public(&ctx_bob.grp, &ctx_bob.d, &ctx_bob.Q, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &ctr_drbg)) != 0)
    {
        mbedtls_printf(" failed\n  ! mbedtls_ecdh_make_public returned -0x%04X\n", -ret);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Exchange public keys between SA and EVCC
    // In a real-world scenario, this would be done over a communication channel
    // Here we just simulate it by copying the public keys to each other's context

    // EVCC Public Key Context
    if ((ret = mbedtls_x509_crt_parse_file(&crt_bob, CRTIFICATE_FILE)) != 0)
    {
        mbedtls_printf(" failed\n  ! mbedtls_x509_crt_parse_file returned -0x%04X\n", -ret);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    mbedtls_ecp_keypair *bob_pub_keypair = mbedtls_pk_ec(crt_bob.pk);

    if ((ret = mbedtls_ecdh_get_params(&ctx_pub_bob, bob_pub_keypair, MBEDTLS_ECDH_OURS)) != 0)
    {
        mbedtls_printf("%d: failed\n  ! mbedtls_ecdh_get_params returned -0x%04X\n", __LINE__, -ret);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    printf("%d: ctx_bob public key\n", __LINE__);
    printf("%d: d\n", __LINE__);
    hexdump(&ctx_bob.d, sizeof(mbedtls_mpi));
    printf("%d: Q\n", __LINE__);
    hexdump(&ctx_bob.Q, sizeof(mbedtls_ecp_point));
    printf("%d: grp\n", __LINE__);
    hexdump(&ctx_bob.grp, sizeof(mbedtls_ecp_group));

    printf("%d: ctx_pub_bob public key\n", __LINE__);
    printf("%d: d\n", __LINE__);
    hexdump(&ctx_pub_bob.d, sizeof(mbedtls_mpi));
    printf("%d: Q\n", __LINE__);
    hexdump(&ctx_pub_bob.Q, sizeof(mbedtls_ecp_point));
    printf("%d: grp\n", __LINE__);
    hexdump(&ctx_pub_bob.grp, sizeof(mbedtls_ecp_group));

    cleanup:
        mbedtls_ecdh_free(&ctx_bob);
        mbedtls_entropy_free(&entropy);
        mbedtls_ctr_drbg_free(&ctr_drbg);
        mbedtls_pk_free(&pk_bob);
        mbedtls_x509_crt_free(&crt_bob);

        return 0;
}
```

Two public keys ctx_bob.Q and ctx_pub_bob.Q printed out should be equal.

Comment: The public key is in the certificate. No derivation is necessary.

Comment: That's correct. But this is the code using mbedtls. I like to put the correct and matched public key into two different structures "mbedtls_ecdh_context" derived from the certificate and private key.

Comment: `mbedtls_ecdh_gen_public` generates a _new_ (ephemeral) keypair replacing the one you read from the file, so it will never match. Also a certificate never contains a privatekey so `ctx.d` _from the certificate_ will be invalid. Rather than pretending to do an ECDH operation you're not actually doing, `mbedtls_ecp_export` will directly get grp from both keys and Q from at least the cert.publickey; it _may_ work for the keyfile or you may need `mbedtls_ecp_keypair_calc_public` depending on the keyfile. But if your actual goal is make sure they match, just use `mbedtls_ecp_check_pub_priv` ...

Comment: ... Finally 'key derivation' or 'derive a key' is a term of art in cryptography and means to create a NEW and DIFFERENT key from an algorithm that uses existing key material; a process to only change the _representation_ or _format_ of an existing key is called something else like 'extract','encode', 'decode',  'pack', 'unpack', 'convert', etc.

Comment: Wow. mbedtls_ecp_check_pub_priv is the one I wanted. Thank you for you help, dave_thompson_085.